# How to use a javascript value inside html style property value

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties

I have created some div(s) on a page. Depending on the browser (or may be any other settings) I want to change the width of these div(s).

Now, if I embed style=" blah blah blah...; width:200px" inside div tag, its ok. But I want this 200px to be, say, 220 sometime or 230 or 240 other times. So what I want now to calculate my required width in javascript, put it in a variable and then insert it as width property value like in &{}...

If I am clear is this possible in this manner, if yes how.

Answer (score 2):

You can set CSS properties on DOM elements in JavaScript:

Say you had a `div` with an `id` of `someDiv`, you could use the following JavaScript to change its width:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var newWidth = 220;
   document.getElementById('someDiv').style.width = newWidth + 'px';
};
```

Comment: Important to note is that CSS properties with dashes `-`, like `background-color`, have to be written camle-cased, like `backgroundColor`.

Comment: ok right. But this way if I call getElementById before the page is loaded, ie the <body> is complete, is gives error Error: document.getElementById("someDiv") is null

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem for now. 
But at the same time raised few queries in my mind.

1 - Isn't that possible putting javascript values as javascript entity inside html tag attribute, I mean the way I wished.

2 - Can you suggest me some good resource on net where I can read and understand DOM & its level 1, 2 and 3. DOM features compatibility with browser's.